# .get('href') returning None instead of href

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi i am trying to scrape the company links from the following website https://www.unpri.org/directory/. However my code keeps returning None instead of the href, here is my code. I tried searching on here, but couldn't seem to find other people with the same problem.

Here is my orignial code

```
from splinter import Browser
import bs4 as bs
import os
import time
import csv

url = 'https://www.unpri.org/directory/'

path = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"
executable_path = {'executable_path': path}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)

browser.visit(url)

source = browser.html

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')



for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="col-xs-8 col-md-9"):
    print(url.get('href', None))
```

Comment: Well, you find the `div`s... don't you then want to find the `a` tags to get **their** `href`s?...

Comment: You are selecting `div` elements (`soup.find_all('div',class_="col-xs-8 col-md-9")`), they usually don't have `href` attribute...

Comment: There are only about nine companies listed on that page. What page on the site is the one that actually interests you?

Comment: Ah, yes of course. I misunderstood the way it worked.  I fixed it now by using print(url.find('a')['href']) instead. Thanks!

Comment: @BillBell The idea is to click "show more" until all links are shown, and then just gather the links.

Comment: You have what you need now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The idea is to click "show more" until all links are shown, and then just gather the links.

I wrote this script using Selenium to click all three buttons until all of the links are shown. It then saves the full page html to a file named `page_source.html`.

The html is then parsed with BeautifulSoup, saved to a dict (`{org_name: url}`) and then dumped to a json file named `organisations.json`.

```
import json
from time import sleep

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException


def click_button_until_all_displayed(browser, button_id):
    button = browser.find_element_by_id(button_id)
    while True:
        try:
            button.click()
        except ElementNotVisibleException:
            break
        sleep(1.2)


BASE_URL = 'https://www.unpri.org'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('{}/directory'.format(BASE_URL))

for button_name in ('asset', 'invest', 'services'):
    click_button_until_all_displayed(driver, 'see_all_{}'.format(button_name))

with open('page_source.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)

driver.close()

with open('page_source.html', 'r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')

orgs = {}
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="col-xs-8 col-md-9"):
    org_name = div.h5.a.text.strip()
    orgs[org_name] = '{}{}'.format(BASE_URL, div.h5.a['href'])

with open('organisations.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(orgs, f, indent=2)
```

It took just under 4 minutes for all of the links to be shown. If you want to save some time, here is a [link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/delirious-lettuce/647e55ffa5f418cb1a69906630ca0cf6) showing this source code, `page_source.html` and `organisations.json`.